Percentile Rank calculation on raster values
I need to perform a "percentile rank" analysis on the values of a raster file. Then later, i will select the first 1% and the top 1% in order to analyze later the lowest and highest values.
I saw these 2 tools:

28.1.15.1. Cell stack percent rank from value
28.1.15.3. Cell stack percentrank from raster layer

From their description, I understand that the one "from raster layer" is more helpful in my case since I only want the rank within the same raster layer.
However, I couldn't quite understand how it works. Here is a screenshot of the second tool:

I need to know each value's percentile rank in this 1 raster. So I don't know why there is an input, and then value and then reference layer. I put the same layer in all of them and the result is a blank output with no values.
I already tried to vectorize to points and then perform the percentile rank analysis in Excel, however the resulting attribute table has around 16 million rows which cannot be open in excel. So that's why I am looking for a way to do this without the need for a vectorization process.

What is the formula for percentile rank?
